# Get value from appsettings.json from array of objects

Tags: asp.net, json

We know that we can get values from json with the IConfiguration class with the GetSection method or simply with `configuration["Serilog:Properties:ApplicationName"];` in case of array with `configuration.GetSection("Serilog.Enrich").Get<string[]>()`

But I don't know how to retrieve the value of "serverUrl" key that is nested in the first node of the WriteTo array

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "Serilog": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
      "ApplicationName": "MyApp"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "http://localhost:5341"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you're using Serilog, why not use [the package they've built to simplify reading settings](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration)? And then if you have a question about how it's reading from appsettings.json, you could always refer to the library code? If you're trying to read elements from some custom array in your appsettings.json that doesn't have convenient methods like Serilog, you could just bind the configuration to a strongly typed object that matches the structure.

Comment: I definitively use .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration) in my program.cs. I have to extrapolate that value for other reason and I'm asking for general purpose when the json node is "complex". But thanks for pointing me that link that answers another doubt (how to parametrize appsetting.xxx.json )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var serverUrl = configuration.GetSection("Serilog").GetSection("WriteTo")
.Get<Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>[]>()[0]["Args"]["serverUrl"];
```

or using c# classes

```
var serverUrl = configuration.GetSection("Serilog").GetSection("WriteTo")
.Get<WriteTo[]>()[0].Args.serverUrl;
```

classes

```
public partial class WriteTo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Args Args { get; set; }
}

public partial class Args
{
    public Uri serverUrl { get; set; }
}
```